# Jquery based WYSIWYG with On-Air possibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, wysiwyg

I have come across http://redactorjs.com which is a very nice wysiwig editor that has on air ability. In other words, in one single line you can turn a static div into an editable text area on the fly.

I -do not- want to pay for it (for some reasons I won't disclose) hence I am looking for an alternative.

Have you ever used a lightweight wysiwig jquery based editor that is easily usable on the fly?

I am looking for something I would use as follow:

```
$("#edit_btn").click(function({
     $("#my_div").turnIntoEditor();
}));

$("#save_btn").click(function({
     $("#my_div").post_content("http://target");
     $("#my_div").turnIntoStatic();
}));
```

Please do not mind the post_content thingy and other function names as they are just given for reference to show the kind of usage I am looking after.

Thank you

Comment: you should checkout another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708801/whats-the-best-edit-in-place-plugin-for-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went for ckeditor. I could use it easily as follow (poc):

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

                <head>
                    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"/>
                    <title>Title</title>


                    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            $("#edit").click(function(){
                                $( '.editable' ).ckeditor();
                            });

                            $("#save").click(function(){
                                var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['editor'];
                                if (editor) { editor.destroy(); }

                                alert($('#editor').html());
                            });
                        });

                    </script>
                </head>
            <body>
                <span id="edit">EDIT</span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <span id="save">SAVE</span><br/><br/>
                <div class="editable" id="editor">
                    Some useless content
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```